Get / List Report Settings via API
I am looking for a way to get report settings through the PowerBI/Graph/Frabic/... API. I specifically interested in getting the 'Export Data' setting for a specific report. The goal would be to able to monitor the export settings of my reports without having to go through each report and opening the settings manually.
Does anyone have a solution for my problem or any suggestions that might set me on the right path?
Thank you for your help!!
I have found an API endpoint that allows you to extract the tenant settings (Tenants - List Tenant Settings - REST API (Admin) | Microsoft Learn), but here the export settings do not give information per report. You can for example enable exports for the whole organisation in the tenant settings, but can disable exports for specific reports in the report settings.
